# Dynamically extract the same object name from a multi level nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to know what is the best way to extract the same named object from a multi level nested object.

I currently have an object that looks like this, and i want to extract out the `parentLocationCluster` objects out of it.

```
 const foo = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'boo',
  parentLocationCluster: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    parentLocationCluster: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'fii',
      parentLocationCLuster: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'faa',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Now I could just a nested `if` statement like so:

```
const { parentLocationCluster } = foo;
if(parentLocationCluster) {
//do something
if(parentLocationCluster.parentLocationCluster) {
  //do something
 }
}
```

but i feel this is significantly inefficient ( which is what i am doing at the moment). Also, the objects could vary with the number of nested parentLocationCluster objects i.e. an object could contain 10 levels of parentLocationClusters.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you need the value of the "deepest" `parentLocationCluster`? Do you want to know if there are `x` levels of `parentLocationCluster`s? Do you...? - Please be more specific on the actual use case.

Comment: Do you want to do something with each of them?

Comment: @andreas "I wanted to know what is the best way to extract the same named object from a multi level nested object."

Comment: @andreas i need the value of ALL names from each parentLocationCluster

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet recursively accesses all nested clusters to any depth and does something with them.

```js
const foo = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'boo',
  parentLocationCluster: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    parentLocationCluster: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'fii',
      parentLocationCluster: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'faa',
      },
    },
  },
};

function readCluster(obj) {
  const cluster = obj.parentLocationCluster
  if (cluster) {
    // Do something
    console.log(cluster.name)
    readCluster(cluster)
  } else
    return;
}

readCluster(foo);
```